# Data Base full backup size

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a job to full backup my database  daily. I have usually between 200 to 300 new records in the database daily. However, size of backup file is always the same and is 7,472 KB. Why this is always fixed while the number of records is increasing. Database Files specifications are as following:

```
Logical Name ------ File Type----Filegroup---Initial Size----Autogrowth/ Maxsize

DBF-----------------Rows Data----PRIMARY-----4---------------by 15 MB, Unlimited

DBF_Data------------Rows Data----FG_Data-----221-------------by 15 MB, Unlimited

DBF_Index-----------Rows Data----FG_Index----3---------------by 15 MB, Unlimited

DBF_Log-------------Log--------Not Applicable- 793--------- by 10 percent,Limited to 2097152 MB
```

This is the code I wrote to make daily backup

```
declare @Date nvarchar(10) 
select @Date=cast( cast(getdate() as date) as nvarchar)

declare @Path nvarchar(100) 
select @Path= 'C:\PAT Daily BK\PAT' + @Date +'.Bak'

BACKUP DATABASE PAT TO DISK =@path
```

Comment: Please show the backup command which is executed.

Comment: If the DB files are ~220MB in size it is unlikely that the backup would be 7MB. Are you looking at the right backup? Restore it to see what's inside.

Comment: I checked it and it is the right DB.

Comment: Have you restored a backup to confirm it's complete? Is the database encrypted?

Comment: DB is not encrypted. I restored and DB has all the new data.

Answer (score 1):

Until your database expands past the initial size, all backups will be the initial size (compression aside).  After it starts expanding, if the expansion amount is set to an amount greater than the space consumed by the additional records then the backup can be expected to stay the same size for multiple days, but eventually will increase when it has to expand again.

SQL Server databases occupy all space allocated whether the data warrants it or not. After it uses up that space it will follow the rules you set for expansion.

Update:  The above explains the observed behavior for encrypted databases, but not for unencrypted databases, as backups of unencrypted databases will be relative to the size of the database.

Comment: But backups do only store allocated pages.

Comment: @usr I don't understand how that is contrary to what I stated.

Comment: He is adding data, yet the backup size does not increase. This answer does not explain this behavior. File expansion has nothing to do with backup size.

Comment: @usr I added a note to my answer, backups of unencrypted databases will be relative to the actual data size, while backups of encrypted databases will occupy the allocated space.  So you're correct unless it's an encrypted database.